# Url not found when loading pages straight from the url in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

Im using vue-router in vue.js. It works fine when Im running it as a local server but as soon as I uploading it to my webserver and enter a page directly it results in "Not found" error,

This works fine running as local server:
http://192.168.2.118:8080/page2

But this:
https://www.mypage.com/page2

results in

> **Not Found** The requested URL was not found on this server.

I have got mode set to "history" to get rid of the # in the url but doesnt seems to have anything to do with the.

Has it anything to do with my webserver?

this is the code in my router.js

```
export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "page1",
            component: Page1
        },
        {
            path: "/page2",
            name: "page2",
            component: () =>
                import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "./views/Page2.vue")
        }
    ]
});
```

This is the full repo for the project:
https://github.com/reppoper/forumpost

**SOLUTION:**

I found a solution by putting this .htaccess file in the root folder. No everything works as expected:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What host are you using? Netlify?

Answer (score 0):

Since your app is a single page client side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a 404 error if they access `http://yoursite.com/page2` directly in their browser.

To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same `index.html` page that your app lives in.

Check the docs to fix this issues on different kind of servers. [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: hm. I have got two webhotels and this works ´http://yoursite.com/page2´ on one but not on the other. Are there any configuration for me to do on the server to get this working?

Comment: found solution. updated my post above

Comment: Nice! That solution works on Apache servers. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations